# Is it necessary to use `do` after condition?

Tags: ruby, block

- This is the official syntax for a `while` loop:

  ```
  while condition [do]
     code
  end
  ```

  But I saw some examples without the `do` after the condition. I was wondering if it is necessary.
- Is there a loop that is equivalent to the Java `do...while` loop? If so, then let me know please

Comment: The square brackets mean it is optional.

Comment: This should have been split into two different questions.

Comment: I'm sorry for this David Grayson, next time i will do if i got 2 questions.

Comment: Anyways, i got an answer for both. So the thread can be closed? :)

Comment: well i tried both: while condition code end and while condition do code end, with the conclusion that both worked. I just was wondering if i'm running wrong with just using the while loop without do after the condition.

Comment: Cary, 1) It's important to not just assume your code is good enough just because it works.  (Especially in some other languages that can lead to disasters.)   2) The answer by jbeck does actually answer both of the OP's questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'do' is optional for the while loop.

You can use:

```
begin
  # do something
end until quit == true
```

for a 'do...while' loop.

Answer (score 1):

Even

```
code while condition
code until condition
```

is valid syntax

Comment: Also an interesting way to use     do...while     in Ruby. Thank you. :)

Comment: By the way: With the solution that jbeck gave to me for the use of do...while, i guess it should be not a problem to do the same with begin... end until quit == false? And: i also found that it is also possible to do something like this: loop.. break if... end. What should i use? which of them is the most efficient one? or are they all the same when you take a look on the running time?

Comment: Doing the exact same would be `begin... end until quit == true`.`loop` runs code in a block - it has different scope. The others are just syntactic differences for the same thing AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

> I saw some examples without the do after the condition. I was wondering if it is necessary.

The `while` loop needs something to tell Ruby when the condition ends and the loop body begins. This can be either one of three things:

- The keyword `do`:

  ```
  while condition do expression end
  ```
- One of the two expression separators, semicolon:

  ```
  while condition; expression end
  ```
- Or newline:

  ```
  while condition
    expression
  end
  ```

There is also an alternative trailing modifier form of the `while` loop, similar to the trailing modifier form of `if`. When the loop body consists only of a single expression, you can also write it as follows:

```
expression while condition
```

Note that you can always turn a series of expressions into a single expression by grouping them with parentheses:

```
(expression1; expression2; expression3) while condition
```

Comment: The 'begin; code; end until condition' will allow the code to run once before the condition is tested, making it the equivalent of the 'do...while' loop.

Comment: @jbeck: Oh, whow, even for a language as inconsistent as Ruby, that is a rather egregious orthogonality violation. I didn't know that.